# Primefaces with Seam

Tags: seam, primefaces, seam2

I am using jboss seam 2.2.1 final, rich-faces (not sure about its version) and primefaces 1.1 in my web project. The project is deployed as an EAR file. When I add the primefaces.jar into the archive (under WEB-INF/lib), all the seam jsf controls (e.g. s:link, s:label, s:div etc.) in my pages cannot be rendered. So, I cannot see those in the browser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using both richfaces and primefaces? You should only use one of them

Comment: Because I need some components from both. Also, I think the problem is not due to the integration of the two. Its about the usage of seam with primefaces.

Comment: There are lots of people using primefaces with seam. Shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: I think you may use richfaces 3.3.1.GA or 3.3.3.GA if you use seam 2.2.1.Final. PrimeFaces is an implementation of JSF 2, but richfaces 3.3 is not. It may be possible to use Primefaces with richfaces 4 after seam 2.3 is released.I happened to see something on primefaces' support forum which said primefaces 2.2 cannot work with richface 3.3, but I cannot find the link now.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING` context-param to `disable`. For more information, see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/GettingStarted.html).